# Not Found when Returning Embedded Collection MongoDB Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am creating an application with embedded review documents inside Course documents with Spring Data Rest and MongoDB but I am unable to get reviews for a course. Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/courses")
public class CourseController {

    private final CourseRepository courseRepository;

    public CourseController(CourseRepository courseRepository) {
        this.courseRepository = courseRepository;
    }

    @PatchMapping("/add-review")
    public List<Review> addReview(@RequestBody AddReviewDto addReviewDto) {
        Course course = courseRepository.findById(addReviewDto.getCourseId()).get();
        Review review = new Review(new ObjectId().toString(), addReviewDto.getReview());

        List<Review> reviews = course.getReviews();
        reviews.add(review);

        course.setReviews(reviews);

        return courseRepository.save(course).getReviews();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/reviews")
    public List<Review> getAllReviewsForCourse(@PathVariable String id) {
        Course course = courseRepository.findById(id).get();

        return course.getReviews();
    }
}
```

Here is the Course model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "courses")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Course {

    public Course(@NotNull String code, @NotNull String name,
                  @NotNull String type, List<Review> reviews) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private String code;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String type;

    private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And Review model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Review {



    @Id
    private String id;

    private String reviewText;

    private String userName;

    private String userId;

    public Review(String id, Review other) {
        this.id = id;
        this.reviewText = other.reviewText;
        this.userId = other.userId;
        this.userName = other.userName;
    }
}
```

When I send a request to http://localhost:8888/courses/605dc41f54beac4412cabadc, I successfully get reviews inside the course object as follows:

```
{
  "code": "CS 101",
  "name": "Introduction to Programming",
  "type": "Lecture",
  "reviews": [
    {
      "reviewText": "dfgsfgdgdg",
      "userName": "yigit",
      "userId": "604a9382777a83b08307c7e8"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I try to send the request to localhost:8888/courses/605dc41f54beac4412cabadc/reviews, I get 404 not found.

I debugged my code and seen that the code is running the correct controller, finding the course object and its reviews are visible in debugger but when I return course.getReviews(), it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be sending to `http://localhost:8888/courses/605dc41f54beac4412cabadc/reviews`
Try to open this URL in your browser

Comment: I sent it to this URL, i didnt write the id explicitly in question

Comment: Yes, I noticed it and edited the question to fix :)

Answer (score 0):

of course you get 404. Because your @RequestMapping is "/courses". try send the request to     `http://localhost:8888/courses/{id}/reviews`

Comment: I am sending it to this url already. Wrote it wrong in question. I can see it is going inside the right controller but not returning reviews

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I have used @Controller instead of @RestController...